# How to use cygwin (or linux command) to rename the files and directories recursively with regular expression

Tags: cygwin, regex

I am using Windows, and trying to use Cygwin to perform this task. I would like to rename the files and directories recursively as following:
From: 
1010110010\ 
1010110010\1010110010.jpg 
1010110010\1010110010.txt 
1010110020\ 
1010110020\1010110020.jpg 
1010110020\1010110020.txt 
...

to: 
1-01-01-1-001-0\ 
1-01-01-1-001-0\1-01-01-1-001-0.jpg 
1-01-01-1-001-0\1-01-01-1-001-0.txt 
1-01-01-1-002-0\ 
1-01-01-1-002-0\1-01-01-1-002-0.jpg 
1-01-01-1-002-0\1-01-01-1-002-0.txt 
...

I was thinking about using for loop, but for loop could not traverse the directories recursively. I can only use for and sed to rename a list of files in a directory:

```
for i in *; do j=`echo $i | sed 's/\(.\)\(..\)\(..\)\(.\)\(...\)\(.\)/\1-\2-\3-\4-\5-\6/g'`; mv $i $j; done
```

But I would like to rename several directories and the files within. So, I tried about "find", but I don't know how to use variables and regular expression with "find" command. Besides that, since I am using Cygwin, I can only use "mv" command instead of "rename" command. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `rename(1)` does not work the same as in Windows. Its syntax is `rename PATTERN REPLACEMENT [files...]`.

Comment: But the rename command is not found in Cygwin. So, I would like to use "mv" to rename the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix has several powerful ways to rename files. Here's one that uses zsh (make sure you have it installed). This first renames the directories, then renames the files in the directories.

```
autoload zmv
zmv -o -i '(?)(??)(??)(?)(???)(?)' '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6'
zmv -o -i '(*)/(?)(??)(??)(?)(???)(?).(*)' '$1/$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7.$8'
```

It's not clear from your question whether the directories can nest. If they do, here's a single command that takes care of both directories and files, taking advantage of the fact that a single pattern replacement works for both:

```
zmv -o -i '(**/)(?)(??)(??)(?)(???)(*)' '$1$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7$8'
```

If you pass the `-n` option to `zmv`, it will show what the command would have done without actually moving the files. I use `-o -i` in my example so that it prompts for confirmation if it would overwrite a file and performs silently otherwise.

`zmv` is documented in the `zshcontrib` man page.

Comment: The command works. But is there any regular expression feature, for example if I want to extract the digits or words?

Comment: @Allen: There are regular expressions in zsh, but not with the usual syntax: instead, you have to use shell patterns, documented (somewhat cryptically) in the `zshexpn` man page. I don't understand what you're after when you ask how to “extract the digits or words”. Maybe you could give a more specific example of what you want to do, perhaps as a separate question?

Comment: Thanks Giles, what I mean "extract the digits or words" are something like \d for digit character and \w for word character.

Comment: @Allen: You can use character sets `[0-9]`, `[A-Z_a-z]`, [[:xdigit:]], etc like in usual regexps. Repetition is done with `#`: `[0-9]#` means 0 or more digits, `[0-9]##` means 1 or more digits. You can also write `<7-42>` to match any integer between 7 and 42 (with or without leading 0s). The full list is under “Filename generation” in the manual; `extended_glob` is automatically enabled in `zmv`.

Answer (score 0):

This will find a bunch of files recursively and do a `mv` to rename them using `sed` to process the names. You can change the file specifications and add your `sed` command.

```
find . \( -name "1*.jpg" -o -name "1*.txt" \) -type f -exec sh -c mv "{}" "$(echo {} | sed '...')" \;
```

Comment: The above suggestion is failed. The result was: mv: `.' and `.' are the same file

Comment: @Allen: I'm sorry, I should have put a `-type f` in it. I overlooked the fact that your directories are named similarly to your files. I'll edit my answer. I'm assuming that you replaced the "..." in the `sed` command with your actual `sed` command.

Comment: @Dennis: I got some error messages: "mv: missing file operand". I already replace the ... with the regular expression. Once I use: find . \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.txt" \) -exec sh -c echo "{}" \;  there will be nothing echo. If I remove the "sh -c", then the file names will be shown

Comment: @Allen: Try single quotes around the shell command: `find . \\( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.txt" \\) -exec sh -c 'echo "{}"' \;` or `find . \\( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.txt" \\) -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(echo {} | sed '...')"' \;`

Comment: @Dennis: The command you mentioned can work only for "echo". It cannot work when using "mv"

Comment: @Allen: Why not? It worked when I tested it.

Comment: @Dennis: I not sure why I cannot work with "mv". I think because 'mv "{}" "$(echo {} | sed ' is assumed as a string, then the regular expression is assumed as the command, and finally '...')"' is another string.

Comment: @Allen: Do you get an error message? What is it?

Comment: Dennis: Error message: $ find . \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.txt" \) -exec sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(echo {} |
 sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9
]\)/\1\.\2\.\3\.\4\.\6\.0\5/g')"' \;
sh: command substitution: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: command substitution: line 0: `echo ./1010110010/1010110010.jpg | sed s/([0-
9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9])([0-9][0-9][0-9])([0-9])/1.2.3.4.6.05/g'
mv: cannot move `./1010110010/1010110010.jpg' to `': No such file or directory

Comment: Dennis: Thanks for your help. I think the "find" command really cannot help to solve my problem recursively. Because -type f will not work correctly since my directory name and the filename have the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

[File::Rename](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.05/lib/File/Rename.pm) or Debian's [`prename`](http://sprunge.us/FMSK) script, both in Perl.